# group/sum with the title

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, javascript-objects

After summing up the values with same rate, i get my object as {10: 310, 101: 120, 110: 110, 120: 360}.
How can i change my reduce method to get the item id written too in the grouped object so that i can identify easily.

This is my code:

```
var myObjArr = [
  { itemid: 12345, desc: "this is item 12345", qty: 8, rate: 101, total: 120 },
  { itemid: 22345, desc: "this is item 22345", qty: 2, rate: 120, total: 240 },
  { itemid: 52345, desc: "this is item 52345", qty: 12, rate: 10, total: 120 },
  { itemid: 42345, desc: "this is item 42345", qty: 1, rate: 110, total: 110 },
  { itemid: 52345, desc: "this is item 52345", qty: 15, rate: 10, total: 150 },
  { itemid: 52345, desc: "this is item 52345", qty: 4, rate: 10, total: 40 },
  { itemid: 22345, desc: "this is item 22345", qty: 1, rate: 120, total: 120 }
];

// var byYear = myObjArr.map(function (item) {// by date
//   var year = new Date(Date.parse(item.date)).getFullYear();
//   return { date: year, total: item.total };
// });

var myGroupedArr = myObjArr.reduce(function (memo, item) {
  memo[item.rate] = (memo[item.rate] || 0) + item.total;
  return memo;
}, {});

console.log(myGroupedArr)//{10: 310, 101: 120, 110: 110, 120: 360}
```

Comment: what does your expected output look like?

Comment: thanks for responding nick!
i just require the itemid to be shown along with the rate and summed amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `itemid` and accumulated `total` to variable and wrap both of these in object.

```js
var myObjArr = [
  { itemid: 12345, desc: "this is item 12345", qty: 8, rate: 101, total: 120 },
  { itemid: 22345, desc: "this is item 22345", qty: 2, rate: 120, total: 240 },
  { itemid: 52345, desc: "this is item 52345", qty: 12, rate: 10, total: 120 },
  { itemid: 42345, desc: "this is item 42345", qty: 1, rate: 110, total: 110 },
  { itemid: 52345, desc: "this is item 52345", qty: 15, rate: 10, total: 150 },
  { itemid: 52345, desc: "this is item 52345", qty: 4, rate: 10, total: 40 },
  { itemid: 22345, desc: "this is item 22345", qty: 1, rate: 120, total: 120 }
];


var myGroupedArr = myObjArr.reduce(function (memo, item) {
  const total = ((memo[item.rate] || {}).total || 0) + item.total;
  const {itemid} = item;
  memo[item.rate] = { total, itemid };
  return memo;
}, {});

console.log(myGroupedArr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the entries as object instead of single value and add `itemid` property.

```
var myGroupedArr = myObjArr.reduce(function (memo, item) {
  if (!memo[item.rate]) {
    memo[item.rate] = { total: item.total, itemid: item.itemid };  
  }
  else {
    memo[item.rate].total += item.total;
  }
  return memo;
}, {});
```

Comment: Realized that it doesn't need store an array of the itemids since they seems to be same for same total?

Comment: @Anis updated answer to include single itemid instead of array (since they seems to be the same for each rate). Please mark as answer if satisfactory.